# I'm writing an algorithm to determine if someone has been hit by a bullet or not

Tags: c#, algorithm, opentk

[Bullet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRsOD.png)

I've been thinking about it for a while, 
but I can't find an answer, so I'm asking a question.
I'm making a game with C# opengl(opentk).
At first, I tried to search the coordinates of the bullet for each pixel to see 
if it hit the enemy. 
That method required too extensive a search.
I'm not asking you to code. 
Just need some tips.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotate the scene so that the trajectory becomes vertical. This is done by applying the transformation

```
X' = (  u.X + v.Y) / √(u²+v²)
Y' = (- v.X + u.Y) / √(u²+v²)
```

to all points. (`(u, v)` defines the shooting direction.)

Now it suffices to check if

```
Xc' - R < Xo' < Xc' + R
```

and

```
Yo' < Yc'
```

[image]